# larger width image to thumbnail

Tags: android, imageview

[image]Url image having width 900*346, we are using same image for displaying detail image and thumbnail image.Thumbnail image is displaying in Gridview with 2 columns and 200dp height but image is stretching.Is there any way to display larger width image with out stretch. Thanks in advance.

**GridView Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_img"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/portfolio_grid_space"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/portfolio_grid_space"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/portfolio_grid_space"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/portfolio_grid_space"
    android:numColumns="2"/>
```

**Gridview Adapter xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Please post your xml file and screen shot.

Comment: @Ravikumar11 look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand, you want to keep image width/height ratio while stretching the image. You can put the below lines in your xml `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

You can play around with `scaleType` to get your desired image.
IF you are using device below API 17, you can custom `ImageView`:

```
public class ScaleAspectFillImageView extends ImageView {

public ScaleAspectFillImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScaleAspectFillImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScaleAspectFillImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // If API level <= 17,
    // Only need custom measurement for image whose size is smaller than imageView size.
    // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        float viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        float viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // Calculate imageView.height based on imageView.width and drawable aspect ratio using scale-aspect-fill mode.
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            float drawableWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            float drawableHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            // Only need custom measurement for image whose size is smaller than imageView size.
            // Avoid divide by zero error.
            boolean needCustomMeasurement = drawableWidth < viewWidth || drawableHeight < viewHeight;
            if (needCustomMeasurement && drawableHeight > 0) {
                float drawableAspectRatio = drawableWidth / drawableHeight;
                // imageView.width and drawable aspect ratio must be greater than zero.
                if (drawableAspectRatio > 0 && viewWidth > 0) {
                    float targetHeight = viewWidth / drawableAspectRatio;
                    setMeasuredDimension((int) viewWidth, (int) targetHeight);
                    return; // Already set the measured dimension.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}

Comment: @Ravikumar11 I edited the answer, you can use custom view with 2 lines above.

Answer (score 0):

Give in the xml file of your layout `android:scaleType="fitXY"`
P.S : this applies to when the image is set with `android:src="..."` rather than `android:background="..."` as backgrounds are set by default to stretch and fit to the View.